# Code First design for 3 tables (one-to-one)

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I am trying to create a database for tracking a parcel as it is being mailed. I am stuck on trying to figure out the best way to implement the relationship between a parcel and its location at any given time/date. Ultimately, I need to be able to look at any moment in the past and tell you where a parcel was and at what time/date. When it entered a location, and when it left a location.

I have three tables for this. (shortened to the basics)

```
public class Parcel
{
    public int ParcelID { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public enum LocationType
{
    Warehouse, Truck
}
public class Location
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Parcel")]
    public int ParcelID { get; set; }
    public LocationType LocationType { get; set; }

    public virtual Parcel Parcel { get; set; }
}
LocationTimeDate
{

}
```

I am not sure how to relate LocationTimeDate to Location. I think it should be a one-to-one relationship. So I'd have to have LocationId. But Location's Key is a ForeignKey (Parcel).

Am I going about this the correct way? Any thoughts/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, to me, a good case for many-to-many relationship with additional information (location, timedate, and parcel). Parcel can have many locations (at different times), and a location might belong to many parcels (at different times). I hope I understand you correctly.

Here is my suggested design:

```
public class Parcel
{
    public int ParcelId { get; set; }

    public List<ParcelAssignment> ParcelAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public LocationType LocationType { get; set; }

    public List<ParcelAssignment> ParcelAssignments { get; set; }
}

public enum LocationType
{
    Warehouse, Truck
} 

public class ParcelAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int ParcelAssignmentId { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int ParcelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParcelId")]
    public Parcel Parcel { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfAssignment { get; set; }
}
```

Your fluent api that goes to your dbcontext class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParcelAssignment>()
            .HasRequired(pa => pa.Parcel)
            .WithMany(p => p.ParcelAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(pa => pa.ParcelId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ParcelAssignment>()
            .HasRequired(pa => pa.Location)
            .WithMany(l => l.ParcelAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(pa => pa.LocationId);
```

You can read more about many-to-many relationships on EF here:

https://practiceaspnet.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/understanding-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-part-i/

https://practiceaspnet.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/understanding-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-part-ii/

Comment: Yes, you do understand what I am wanting. I like your thoughts. I will test it out this evening when I finish with work, and will get back to you. Thanks so much for your feedback!

Comment: Thanks, @erkaner. Your response has been very helpful.